# Intercept residuals correlated with level-one residuals in MLM

Tags: mixed-model, residuals, diagnostic

I am running my ever first multi-level model. The model has three fixed effects and a random intercept by the grouping factor "participant id".

The outcome variable is "bone mineral density". The three fixed effect predictors are "lean body mass", "fat mass", and "age". Lean mass, fat mass and bone mineral density were measured three times - baseline, year one and year two. I had 128 participants, giving 504 observations in total. There was no missing data.

I am checking the assumptions. I have checked the following:

- Level one and level two residuals are normally distributed with a mean of zero: confirmed = no problem.
- Level-one residuals are independent of the level-one predictors (lean mass and fat mass): confirmed = no problem.
- Level-two residuals are independent of the level-two predictor (age): confirmed = no problem.
- Level-one residuals are independent of the level-two predictor: confirmed = no problem.

**The problem is in the final check:

- The level-one residuals ARE correlated with the intercept residuals  (r = 0.275)**

[image: Correlation of level-one and level-two residuals]

I do not need to solve this problem as such, not for now anyway. But, I would like to try and understand it and offer an explanation as to how I might investigate this further or how I might explain it.

1. Does it have anything to do with the fact that I only had three observations for each participant?
2. Is it telling me that I am missing predictors in the model, or perhaps, missing predictors in the random effects part of the model?

Extra information: Conditional R2 = 0.966, and marginal R2 = 0.910.

```
Linear mixed model fit by REML. t-tests use Satterthwaite's method ['lmerModLmerTest']
Formula: BMDtotal ~ 1 + leanMass_kg + fatMass_kg + age + (1 | id)
   Data: bmf_dataw_long

REML criterion at convergence: 1481.2

Scaled residuals: 
    Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
-6.9223 -0.2938  0.0514  0.3555  9.3134 

Random effects:
 Groups   Name        Variance Std.Dev.
 id       (Intercept) 0.9775   0.9887  
 Residual             0.5871   0.7662  
Number of obs: 504, groups:  id, 168

Fixed effects:
             Estimate Std. Error        df t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)  18.83228    1.41555 172.65282  13.304  < 2e-16 ***
leanMass_kg  -0.40176    0.01428 350.68332 -28.134  < 2e-16 ***
fatMass_kg    0.82097    0.01274 436.67920  64.430  < 2e-16 ***
age           0.11966    0.02265 160.43660   5.283  4.1e-07 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Correlation of Fixed Effects:
            (Intr) lnMss_ ftMss_
leanMass_kg -0.381              
fatMass_kg  -0.226 -0.010       
age         -0.908  0.025  0.021
```

Thanks for any advice.